# Changes made via SSH WILL BE LOST if the instance is replaced by auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to install a gRPC PHP extension on my elastic beanstalk created EC2 instances. I have auto-scaling enabled, and when a new EC2 instance is kicked in, I lose all my installations.

From the documentation, I found two ways to fix this:

1. Create an instance and download everything required and take an image of that instance. And add the image id (AMI ID) in the Elastic Beanstalk environment (Under Configuration -> Instances). And every new instance created by auto-scaling will be from the image I provide. This approach never worked for me. Am I missing something here?
2. Write a config file in the .ebextensions to automatically install all the required extensions whenever a new instance is kicked in. And for this, we need to create a yaml/json file as per the documentation in cloud.google.com/php/grpc.

Can someone guide which approach should be taken? And help me create yaml/json file to automate the process for all the instances in auto scaling?

Comment: Why did the AMI approach never work for you?

Comment: It was still showing me install gprc error when new instances were kicked in.

Answer (score 3):

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html), to customize your Elastic Beanstalk environment you should use `.ebextensions` configuration files.

Creating `.ebextensions` provides the ability to completely customize the instances and environment that your application is running on/in, and makes upgrades, changes and/or additions to your instances and environment straightforward and efficient.

As a sidenote, ssh’ing to ElasticBeanstalk instances, and making on-instance changes, should be avoided. The autoscaling issue you are facing is one reason, however the other major reason is that making changes on the instance itself will cause the instances state to be out of sync with the EB state is expecting. If the state is out of sync, subsequent deployments will fail because the application version EB is expecting has drifted. Managing your application and environment through code and `.ebextensions` eliminates this issue.